# ASP.NET: Unable to cast IO.StreamWriter to IO.MemoryStream

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, io, stream, memorystream

I have a complex class module that make a lot of processing and return a object of type `IO.StreamWriter`, but I need cast this object to `IO.MemoryStream`, furthemore to `Byte()`. Finally it converts `Byte()` to `Base64String` that ajax consumes and generate a CSV file.

I made this with `DynamicPDF.Document`, but this library has a method that returns binary.

```
Dim objSW As IO.StreamWriter = EXP.ExportarBinario(objCommand, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream, 1)
Dim objMS As New MemoryStream()

objSW.BaseStream.CopyTo(objMS)

Dim objArrayByte As Byte() = objMS.ToArray()

Dim strArrayByte64 As String = String.Format("data:{0};base64,{1}", "application/vnd.excel", Convert.ToBase64String(objArrayByte))

Return strArrayByte64
```

Comment: "I have a complex class module"  If a class is a class module then does that mean that a module is a module module? Maybe just call a class a class and a module a module.

Comment: When posting code, please don't leave a huge wad of whitespace before each line.  It just makes it harder for us to read for no good reason.  You can hold the Alt down while selecting text in VS to allow you to select a block from anywhere. This let's you select code while cutting out unnecessary indenting.

Comment: I have wanted to say that I have a module full of classes.
All them are interconected.

Comment: Interconnectedness isn't relevant. Each class should be declared in its own code file and so should each module. There's rarely good reason to declare one type inside another unless it is private. The fact that one type uses an instance of another type is simply how programming works.

Comment: Fixed the code in post question.

Comment: Ok, but do you have a solution for my issue?